# {'DisallowedError props: `content, files`'} and Unhanled Rejection at Promise Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const config = {
  name: "itunes",
  description: "search info music in iTunes",
  usage: "itunes [name]",
  version: "1.0.0-endupdate",
  cooldown: 5,
  credits: "Xavia Team"
};
const langData = {
  "vi_VN": {
    "missingInput": "Vui lòng nhập tên bài hát",
    "notFound": "Không tìm thấy bài hát",
    "results": "Tên bài hát: {name}\nNghệ sĩ: {artist}\nAlbum: {album}\nNgày xuất bản: {release_date}\nGiá tiền: {price}\nThời lượng: {length}\nThể loại: {genre}\n",
    "error": "Đã có lỗi xảy ra!"
  },
  "en_US": {
    "missingInput": "Please enter the name of a song",
    "notFound": "Song not found",
    "results": "Song title: {name}\nArtist: {artist}\nAlbum: {album}\nRelease date: {release_date}\nPrice: {price}\nLength: {length}\nGenre: {genre}\n",
    "error": "An error occurred!"
  },
  "ar_SA": {
    "missingInput": "يرجى إدخال اسم الأغنية",
    "notFound": "لم يتم العثور على الأغنية",
    "results": "عنوان الأغنية: {name}\nالفنان: {artist}\nالألبوم: {album}\nتاريخ الإصدار: {release_date}\nالسعر: {price}\nالمدة: {length}\nالنوع: {genre}\n",
    "error": "حدث خطأ!"
  }
};
async function onCall({ message, args, getLang }) {
  try {
    const input = args.join("+").toLowerCase();
    if (!input) return message.reply(getLang("missingInput"));
    const encodedInput = encodeURIComponent(input);
    const res = await global.GET(`https://api.popcat.xyz/itunes?q=${encodedInput}`);
    const musicData = res.data;
    if (!musicData) return message.reply(getLang("notFound"));
    const thumbnailStream = await global.getStream(musicData.thumbnail);
    return message.reply({
      content: getLang("results", {
        url: musicData.url,
        name: musicData.name,
        artist: musicData.artist,
        album: musicData.album,
        release_date: musicData.release_date,
        price: musicData.price,
        length: musicData.length,
        genre: musicData.genre
      }),
      files: [{
        attachment: thumbnailStream
      }]
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    message.reply(getLang("error"));
  }
}
export default {
  config,
  langData,
  onCall
}
// ThuHang:))
```

Help me:(

Comment: Hi Phat Tran andf welcome to Stack Overflow. You would not have been able to post this question if you had formatted the code - some minimum introduction, description of the problem and information on where and how the error occurs is both expected and required. There are links on this page to the help center and tour for new users that you can follow to help edit the post into a form that we can help you with.